# How to reinit the NumberAxis and move to next value in JavaFX LineChart?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, linechart

I am currently trying to create a chart, which allows me to restart the x-axis and continue drawing. The axis range is 0-100, but when the graph reaches 100 need the following values is again 0. But what makes the chart is to be returned to the initial zero.

in the next two picture I show how to work the chart currently.

[image]

what makes the chart is to be returned to the initial zero and continue.
[image: what makes the chart is to be returned to the initial zero.]

I need something like this:
[image]

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `axis.setTickLabelFormatter()` to format tick labels:

```
public class TickLabelFormatterDemo extends Application
{

    private static final int RANGE = 100;
    private int last_X_Axis_Val = 20;


    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage )
    {
        stage.setTitle( "Sample" );

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange( false);
        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter( new StringConverter<Number>()
        {

            @Override
            public String toString( Number object )
            {
                int i = object.intValue() % RANGE;
                return String.valueOf( i == 0 ? RANGE : i );
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString( String string )
            {
                return null;
            }
        } );

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart
                = new LineChart<>( xAxis, yAxis );

        lineChart.setTitle( "Monitoring" );
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName( "Values" );

        Random random = new Random();

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline( new KeyFrame( Duration.seconds( 2 ), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( ActionEvent event )
            {
                if ( series.getData().size() > 5 )
                {
                    series.getData().remove( 0 );
                }
                series.getData().add( new XYChart.Data( last_X_Axis_Val, random.nextInt( 50 ) ) );
                last_X_Axis_Val += 20;
            }
        } ) );
        timeline.setCycleCount( Timeline.INDEFINITE );
        timeline.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene( lineChart, 800, 600 );
        lineChart.getData().add( series );

        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }

}
```