# JavaFX LineChart with many entrys

Tags: user-interface, charts, javafx

i want to display the cpu usage in a line chart. The Problem it, that if there are to many entrys i becomes confused. I tried to delete the first entry after X entrys but then the chart is not fully used. I want, that the line chart is filled with data but from begining to end.

[Example with many entrys and delet the first one](http://s22.postimg.org/5u4xqp0dt/Unbenannt.png)

Here is some example code:

This is the Controller, where i create the series and start the Thread to update my data.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML private LineChart chart;
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    chart.getData().add(series);
    ThreadTest updateChart = new ThreadTest(series);
    Thread test = new Thread(updateChart);
    test.start();
}
```

}

Here is the thread to update the data and after more then 10 entrys have been added i remove the first one, so that there are not to many entrys on the chart. I tried also to move after remove the first one to get the rest of the entrys and set them to 0-X so that there is always an first one. But i think the series do this autmaticly but i dont get an exception if i try to remove the first item over and over again.

```
public class ThreadTest extends Task<Void>{

private int chartCounter;
private XYChart.Series series;
private boolean running=true;

public ThreadTest(XYChart.Series series){
    this.series=series;
}

@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {
    while(running){
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(chartCounter, (int)(Math.random() * 10)));
    System.out.println("Test");
    chartCounter++;
    if(series.getData().size()>10){
        series.getData().remove(0);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Thanks for help!!

Comment: If you're getting this chart displayed, you are clearly doing something wrong in your code. Without seeing your code, it is impossible to know what that might be. Please create (probably from scratch) a *minimal* and *executable* example that shows this behavior (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it.

Comment: I added a simple example.

Comment: Any one know the solution?

Comment: Without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no.

Comment: You can download a Project to import in Netbeans here. It is ready to use

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=56542925663953032731

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: You may shift the data shown, to reduce resource usae. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29623522