# JavaFX paus thread on scene change and resume

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, javafx, task

im searching for a way to paus a thread that for example displays some animation on a scene by switching to a different one. The background is to save cpu load of to mutch executing tasks. I also want to resume the Thread after i switch back to the scene. I know that i can do this in the method, in which i load the new scene but i cant find a way to pause and resume on that point the thread stoped. Is there an build in function in task, futuretask? My only idea was, to save the current state and by switching back i start a new task and restore the saved values/state. Are there any experts, who can give me the best practise/solution? Thanks for your help!

Sry for no code, but i think you can awnser it without any example. When not i will add some example code for sure.

Comment: this link may help : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I already read this and i know the ServiceClass has methods to pause, cancel and restart an Thread/Service. I tried i my self but i dont get it to restart. Have you an working example for me?

Comment: Add [your sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: Hey, can you also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291239/javafx-linechart-with-many-entrys